# undefined variable and index in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting an undefined variable and undefined index notices that I thought **isset()** should have done away with.  In this example I'm reading through a db consisting of individuals names and their companies.  I want to separate out the unique companies, so I know how many times they are represented.  Here's what I'm expecting it to do:

1. Open the database, count the entries, load up the first row from the table.
2. The first 'if' inside the 'for' loop looks to see if the $comp variable with a hash value of the company name exists.  If it does, increment the count
3. If $comp variable is not set, this is the first time I've seen this company so go to the 'else'.

However, **isset()** does not seem to be working because PHP is still throwing me notices about that line of code and that my variable and indexes aren't defined.

```
   $r1Q   = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM totals", $db);
   $r1C   = mysql_num_rows($r1Q);
   $r1    = mysql_fetch_array($r1Q);

    $title = "Companies Most Represented in DB";

    printf("
    <div class=\"content\">
    <h2>%s</h2>
    <center>
    <table border=1 bgcolor=#ffffff>
    <tr bgcolor=#cc9933>
        <th width=150>Company</th>
        <th width=50>Times</th>
    </tr>
    ", $title);

   // loop through 1 time for each entry in the db
   for($j=0;$j<$r1C;$j++) {
        $company = $r1[4];

        // have i seen this company before?
        if(isset($comp[$company])) {
            $cnt[$company]++;
            $cnt1[$company]++;
        }
        else {
            $comp[$company] = $r1[4];
            $cnt[$company]  = 1;
            $cnt1[$company] = 1;
        }
```

Comment: "that line of code" is... what? For that matter what is the text of the error message?

Comment: I don't see where you create the $comp array. Is there more code above this?

Comment: Sorry, "that line of code" is the line with the `if(isset())`.  If you see my comments on other posts below, I've now defined the arrays, but I still get notices about Undefined variables.  If I just simply turn off the notices (`error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);`) the page prints fine.

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize the arrays either:

Add this before the loop:

```
 $comp = array();
 $cnt = array();
 $cnt1 = array();
```

Comment: Good improvement, but not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I believe is not your isset() function, but the line before that where you reference [4] of `$r1`.

```
for($j=0;$j<$r1C;$j++) {
   $company = $r1[4];
```

I think this index may not exist, since isset should work just fine in the following statement.

```
for($j=0;$j<$r1C;$j++) {
   if(isset($r1[4])) {
     $company = $r1[4];
   }else{
     // Handle Error
   }
   // Rest of your for statement
}
```

Without seeing all of the code and what line the error happens on, this is a lot more difficult to narrow down. Many errors occur where users often forget to look, or post onto the site.

Comment: Here is an example of the first two errors:

`Notice: Undefined variable: seen in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\companySearch.php on line 781

Notice: Undefined index: IBM in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\companySearch.php on line 781`

Line 781 refers to my if(isset()) line of code above. I have verified that the $company =$r1[4] is not indeed NULL, it has a value.

Comment: I've followed the previously suggested code updates.  I've defined the variables as arrays and I've added the `&& $comp[$company] != false`.  I still get the Undefined variable message.  

It is worth noting too that as soon as I set `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);` the page prints out the generated table of companies perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Simple edit to your if statement:

```
if(isset($comp[$company]) && $comp[$company] != false) { // edit was made here
            $cnt[$company]++;
            $cnt1[$company]++;
}
```

Because the key may exist but it may not have a value, so what will it increment from? It won't just assume 0, since it could also be another type. Any number other than 0 will be equal to false in PHP, so you can add the additional comparison above to fix your problem.

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify that the variable is indeed an array in PHP.

Use this example for the docs linked below:

```
$firstquarter = array('January', 'February', 'March');
```

[PHP array docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php)